# Deploy Spring boot Freemarker application to cpanel Tomcat server

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, deployment, cpanel, freemarker

I am trying to deploy Freemarker Spring boot application to cpanel  but I didn't manage to do it this is my htaccess file in public_html folder:

```
SetHandler jakarta-servlet
SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

I upload the war file int public_html folder and create a folder same name as a war file:
this is the log of tomcat:

```
-Nov-2022 10:10:06.074 INFO [user.host-startStop-6] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/home/user/public_html/platform] has finished in [14] ms
10-Nov-2022 10:24:26.127 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/platform]
10-Nov-2022 10:24:26.134 INFO [user.host-startStop-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/home/user/public_html/platform.war]
10-Nov-2022 10:24:26.221 INFO [user.host-startStop-7] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/home/user/public_html/platform.war] has finished in [87] ms
```

And this is the server.xml file :

```
<Host name="user.host" appBase="/home/user/public_html" unpackWARs="true"
deployXML="true" autoDeploay="true">
<Alias>www.user.host</Alias>
<Alias>user.host</Alias>
<Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/user/public_html" debug="1"/>
```

Where I am wrong how to deploy on cpanel tomcat server and how to access the application.

Comment: what is the error, where did you struggled with. ?

Comment: Is return 404 not found when I open the  domain url `The requested resource [/] is not available`